# create path from several file objects or just one

Tags: java

I am working on different platforms (Solaris/Windows). I need to create a **File** object which contains several path elements. The question is: is it better to create the final File object "step by step" or in a single call. The latter one assumes that Java does the right path mapping on different platforms. Does it always do a correct mapping due to different file separators?

```
File parent = // some directory;

// Use several file objects...
File myFile1 = new File(new File(new File(parent, "part1"), "part2"), "myfile");

// .. or use just on (on all platforms!)?
File myFile2 = new File(parent, "part1/part2/myfile");
```

The first solution is probably (a) slower and (b) less readable...

Comment: If you plan to do io-operations, don't mind that one of these two approaches is "slower" than the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the 2nd one, and instead of hard-coding the forward slash, use `File.separatorChar` / `File.separator`:

> The system-dependent default name-separator character. This field is initialized to contain the first character of the value of the system property file.separator. On UNIX systems the value of this field is '/'; on Microsoft Windows systems it is '\'.

Note that you don't need to do this with Sun's JVM - the `Win32FileSystem` class translates forward to backward slashes - if you look at its code, it has `slash` and `altSlash`, and in case `altSlash` (`/`) is encountered, the class normalizes the path

But, as pointed in the comments, in order to remain confident that your code will be portable, use the `File.separator`

Comment: Do you know of a JRE that doesn't understand that the slash is a path separator? I don't. Sun's library allows you to use either forward or backward slashes on any platform. Granted, as far as I know it's not *documented* behavior and therefore a different, greenfield implementation could be more restrictive. I bet a large amount of code would then break on that implementation, though.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder you are right. I added a clarification about that.

Comment: I think **you're** right as well: Relying on Sun's behavior means one's code wouldn't work on some hypothetical file system that uses a different character for a separator that the lib can't do this with because of ambiguity (say, `-`). I figure that's why the behavior isn't (and probably won't be) documented. Granted it's an "out there" scenario, but relying on undocumented behavior is always a least a *little* (and sometimes a lot) risky.

Comment: Just a note: As far as I know, plain Win32 API understands directly both  \ and /. The problem in Win32 is that many layers / components on top of Win32 do not like `/`, but if you use just Win32 and forward slashes, it works OK. See the first note under http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247#maxpath. Anyway, you should always use `File.separator`, as relying in a particular implementation is not portable.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any advantage in solution (1). Both will create a valid `File` object and, for sure, the second solution is easier to understand, as it clearly shows, that you have a path that is relative to some parent folder.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you wanted to do some operation on parent File objects (e.g. if directory is exists) or reuse parent File objects for multiple files there is no advantage on first solution. If you are creating File object for only one file use second. That is less verbose.